# Android trim/split/cut video using SDK/NDK

Tags: android, video, sdk, android-ndk, trim

I have heard of FFMPEG but i am not able to understand how to integrate it in my android code and use the methods of ffmpeg to trim the video.

Does anyone knows about video trimming library in android or NDK.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "FFMPEG [android-ndk]". That's a rather popular theme around here.

Comment: Check out- https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/